# navigation bar not working in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Below is my code. I have created my custom nav bar as it has to come above a image in bootstrap. But links are not working. U can visit [this](http://hrlwebproducts.com/brandjockeying/) for a working site. I am using bootstrap for the first time.

```
<ul class="newnav"  data-toggle="collapse">
    <li class="hidden">
        <a href="#page-top"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About us</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#team">Team</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: On a side note... your background image is (png) 1.6MB big. Use some compression for god sake - jpeg with high compresison ration should shring that by a lot.

Comment: you are right ... but plz help me with links...

Comment: trying from past 4 hours .. not getting wats wrong with the links. only the first link <a href="#page-top"></a> is working and others are not working..

Comment: i copied the source code into dreamweaver and the links worked. something to do with the image

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue with javascript error in contact_me.js file line number 3. Resolve that error and see. (for error see in firebug console)